# why isn't the @Transactional annotation working?

Tags: java, spring, transactions

This code is about some database actions:

```java
@Component("trans")
 public class CustomerTransactionImp extends JdbcDaoSupport{

    public static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CustomerTransactionImp.class.getName());

    @Autowired
    public CustomerTransactionImp(DataSource dataSource) {
        setDataSource(dataSource);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void deleteCustomerByName(String name){
        String sql = "DELETE FROM CUSTOMER WHERE firstName = ?";

        deleteCustomerByID((long) 100);
        displayAllCustomer();
        logger.info("Deleted customer named: "+ name);
        getJdbcTemplate().update(sql,name);
    }

    public void deleteCustomerByID(Long ID) {
        String sql = "DELETE FROM CUSTOMER WHERE id = ?";

        logger.info("Deleted customer named: "+ ID);
        getJdbcTemplate().update(sql, ID);
    }

    public List getAllCustomer(){
        String sql = "Select * FROM customer";

        return getJdbcTemplate().queryForList(sql);
    }

    public void displayAllCustomer() {
        for (Object o : getAllCustomer()) {
            System.out.println(o);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my *Spring* configuration file:

```xml
    <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
    <context:component-scan base-package="database.transactionmanagement"/>

    <jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource">
        <jdbc:script location="sqlfiles/schema.sql"/>
        <jdbc:script location="sqlfiles/data.sql"/>
    </jdbc:embedded-database>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <constructor-arg name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

And my test class:

```java
 @Test
public void trans_management_test() {
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("databaseconf/transaction-conf.xml");

    CustomerTransactionImp customerTransactionImp = context.getBean("trans", CustomerTransactionImp.class);

    customerTransactionImp.deleteCustomerByName("Omer");
    customerTransactionImp.displayAllCustomer();
}
```

So basic codes, in the code where I use the `@Transactional` annaotation, I created a wrong SQL query, the table is not my db-:

```
 String sql = "DELETE FROM CUSTOMERWrong WHERE firstName = ?";
```

I mean, in the `deleteCustomerByName` method, here is `deleteCustomerByID` method and this method is working fine and commit.

According to transaction, `deleteCustomerByID` method must not commit or my understanding of the `@Transactional` annotation will be wrong. The SQL query under `deleteCustomerByName` method is wrong while the SQL query under `deleteCustomerByID` is okay, all of them must not commit???

Comment: try to add `@Transactional` on deleteCustomerByID method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem , @Transactional is used in any service class (Customer, Manager) and also use the real-time database, I was using the database that is ran on RAM. My new code is as following:

```
@Test
    public void trans_management_test() {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("databaseconf/transaction-conf.xml");

        CustomerManager customerTransactionImp = context.getBean("manager", CustomerManager.class);
        customerTransactionImp.operation("Administration", 110);
    }

@Component("trans")
public class CustomerTransactionImp extends JdbcDaoSupport{

    public static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CustomerTransactionImp.class.getName());

    @Autowired
    public CustomerTransactionImp(DataSource dataSource) {
        setDataSource(dataSource);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void deleteCustomerByName(String name){
        String sql = "DELETE FROM departments WHERE department_name = ?";

        logger.info("Deleted customer named: "+ name);
        getJdbcTemplate().update(sql,name);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void deleteCustomerByID(Long ID) {
        String sql = "DELETE FROM departments WHERE department_id = ?";

        logger.info("Deleted customer named: "+ ID);
        getJdbcTemplate().update(sql, ID);
    }

@Component("manager")
public class CustomerManager {

    @Autowired
    CustomerTransactionImp transactionImp;

    @Transactional
    public void operation(String name , long ID){
        transactionImp.deleteCustomerByID(ID);
        transactionImp.deleteCustomerByName(name);
    }

    public CustomerTransactionImp getTransactionImp() {
        return transactionImp;
    }

 <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
    <context:component-scan base-package="database.transactionmanagement"/>

    <bean id="datasource2" class="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/hr"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value=""/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <constructor-arg name="dataSource" ref="datasource2"/>
    </bean>
```